# My elif/if statements are not working

Tags: python

```
choice=str("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z")
choice1=str("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z")
choice2=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
user=int(len(input("Enter password")))
while user <6 and user <12:
    user=int(len(input("The password needs to be at least 6 characters and no more than 12, enter password again")))
print("password accepted")

if user in (choice2) or   str(choice) or  (choice1):
    print("password is weak")
elif user in  (choice2) and  str(choice1) or  (choice) and (choice) or  (choice1) and (choice2):
    print("your password is medium")
elif user in (choice2) and  (choice1) and  (choice):
    print("your password is strong")
```

when user enters a password like :

```
Enter passwordJnnnnn
password accepted
password is weak
```

it still replies their password is weak, when its suppose to say their password is medium

when i add this:

```
if user in (choice2) or user in str(choice) or user in (choice1):
    print("password is weak")
elif user in  (choice2) and user in   str(choice1) or  user in (choice) and  (choice) or user in   (choice1) and  (choice2):
    print("your password is medium")
elif user in (choice2) and user in  str(choice1) and user in   (choice):
    print("your password is strong")
```

it still does not work as:

```
Enter passwordLhgg12
password is weak
```

it replies with weak when its suppose to be strong

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your condition to :

```
if user in (choice2) or user in str(choice) or user in (choice1):
```

And like this for other conditions.

That's because python will evaluated `str(choice)` as True and always the first condition would be True.

Read the details in [Truth Value Checking](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Answer (score 0):

You need a boolean expression between each and/or

You evaluated your while loop just fine with

```
while user <6 and user <12:
```

Your if statement doesn't carry the `in` across the conditions, so I think by this

```
if user in (choice2) or   str(choice) or  (choice1):
```

You meant this

```
if user in (choice2) or user in str(choice) or user in  (choice1):
```

Same goes for the other elifs

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems with your code:

```
choice=str("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z")
```

What you probably want is alist of all characters, which does not include `','` 25 times, so

```
choice = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"  # no need for str(), it is already a str
```

Then, `choice2` is a tuple of integers... I guess you wanted characters again:

```
choice2 ="0123456789"
```

Here you ask for password, forget the password and store length of password in variable named `user` (btw, `int(len(X))` is the same as just `len(X)`):

```
user=int(len(input("Enter password")))
```

Here you check whether user is both less than 6 and less then 12 (of course it's <12 if it is <6):

```
while user <6 and user <12:
    ...
```

I guess you really wanted:

```
password = input("Enter password")
while not (6 <= len(password) <= 12):
    ...
```

This, **your main question**:

```
if user in (choice2) or   str(choice) or  (choice1):
    print("password is weak")
```

checks whether either of these is true:

- user (an integer, password length) is in choice2 (numbers 0 - 9), i.e. user < 10
- str(choice) is not an empty string
- choice1 is not false (0, None, "", [], False are all false)

That will always pass!

I guess in your tests you wanted to check whether password included characters from choice, ( and choice1 and choice2). For that, you can do:

```
any(ch in choice1 for ch in password)  # is any character from password in choice1?
```

or

```
set(password) & set(choice1)  # is there any overlap between contents of the two?
```

Comment: `choice = string.ascii_uppercase; choice2 = string.digits`

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Thanks, I never knew about those :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said about the comparison operators not being distributive, `user` is an `int` where `choice` and `choice1` are strings. I believe you will get an error if you try `bool(user in choice1)`.

You could save the input as a variable separate from its length, and also create a set to make the comparisons:

```
password = raw_input("Input password:\n>>")
pass_length = len(password)
pass_chars = set(password)
```

Then your `choice` categories would also need to be sets, but you'd be able to write your `if/elif` as you already have:

```
if pass_chars in choice or pass_chars in choice1:
```

...etc